# Check Javascript "oncontextmenu" event support in the Safari browser on iPhone and iPad devices

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, contextmenu

We all know that **Apple** has decided to make **Safari** compete for the coveted "creative browser" award (ousting the defunct Internet Explorer) by deciding, among the many creative and non-standard solutions undertaken, to "ignore" the `oncontextmenu` event on his **iPhone** and **iPad** devices, but I ask you all:

1. For what masochistic reason does the `if( "oncontextmenu" in window )` test still return a positive result on these devices (a real misdirection)?
2. Is there a "clean" way to check if `oncontextmenu` is really supported and triggered by the browser that is not a fallback to an `if( /iPad|iPhone|iPod/i.test( navigator.platform ) )` style solution?

Answer (score 0):

Never thought about it before, I used to test `passiveSupported` feature but this one I never thought about. Would you give the below one try. It basically should work for all the mouse events:

```js
function testEvent(mEvtName, node = document){
    const onEvent = "on" + mEvtName;
    node[onEvent] = (function(evt){
        this.removeEventListener(mEvtName, node[onEvent]);
        this[onEvent] = void(0);
        evt.type && (this[mEvtName+"EventSupported"] = true);
    }).bind(node);
    node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(mEvtName));
}

testEvent("click") //documen

t.clickEventSupported === true
testEvent("contextmenu") //document.contextmenuEventSupported === true/false
```

```js
(async () => {
function testEvent(mEvtName, node = document){
    const onEvent = "on" + mEvtName;
    node[onEvent] = (function(evt){
        this.removeEventListener(mEvtName, node[onEvent]);
        this[onEvent] = void(0);
        evt.type && (this[mEvtName+"EventSupported"] = true);
    }).bind(node);
    node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(mEvtName));
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  testEvent("contextmenu");
});

const contextmenuSupported = await new Promise(res => {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    setTimeout(() => document.contextmenuEventSupported ? res(true) : res(false), 17);
  });
})

//do something here
console.log(contextmenuSupported)

})()
```

Comment: copy paste the function in the console and run it . Then check `contextmenuEventSupported` property on the element. By default the element is document itself. So you can attach this function to be called on DOMContentLoaded or onload event of the window and observe the value. I will post a example.

Comment: I added an example embedded here

Comment: Perfect thanks. Tomorrow I'll run the script from an iPhone in the office and let you know the outcome of the test.

Comment: Np, you do not need the use async function, setTimout or await, because dispatchEvent calls the handler synchronously. It is an automatic habbit of mine. You can check `document.contextmenuEventSupported` right inside the first DOMContentLoaded event, just after `testEvent`

Comment: The test returns TRUE on the latest generation iPhone

Comment: of course it does because contextmenu translates to 'longpress' event on iphone, so it DOES support it. Your issue looks like an A-B-C problem